# Mayavi not playing nice with ipywidgets in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-2.7, button, mayavi, ipywidgets

Is there any reason why Mayavi will not work along with ipywidgets inside a Jupyter notebook? I can display a x3d Mayavi image inline inside the notebook using 'mlab.init_notebook()', like so:

```html
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
mlab.init_notebook()
mlab.clf()
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:11j, 0:2*np.pi:11j]
x = np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)
mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
mlab.mesh(x, y, z, representation='wireframe', color=(0, 0, 0))
```

However, if I add a Button (ipywidget) to call back a function to plot the same Mayavi figure, the plot does not show anywhere.

```html
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
mlab.init_notebook()

def click(a):

    mlab.clf()
    phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:11j, 0:2*np.pi:11j]
    x = np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    z = np.cos(phi)
    mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
    mlab.mesh(x, y, z, representation='wireframe', color=(0, 0, 0))

button=widgets.Button(description='Click Me')
button.on_click(click)

display(button)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `IPython.display.display` to have it render to notebook (done implicitly when a mayavi object is the return value of the last `mesh()` call):

```
from IPython.display import display

obj = mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
display(obj)
```

As mayavi does not interactively update the plots for notebooks, you will need to call display again in the button callback. In case the button is clicked several times, you should also clear away the previous plot with `IPython.display.clear_output`:

```
from IPython import display, clear_output

def click(a):
    mlab.clf()
    ...
    f = mlab.figure()
    mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
    mlab.mesh(x, y, z, representation='wireframe', color=(0, 0, 0))
    clear_output(wait=True)
    # Since we clear outputs, we also need to redisplay button
    display(button, f)
```